Should there be a comma after the year in “the October 29, 2024 meeting”?
This is the sentence in question:

during the October 29, 2024 meeting, the participants discussed the problems.

The grammar checker in Word suggests putting a comma after "2024", so it would become “October 29, 2024, meeting” but that personally feels awkward. Which is grammatically correct and why?

Grammarly says: "here is a rule of thumb: in the month-day-year format (used in the United States), place commas after the day and year. In the day-month-year format (used in the UK and other countries), do not use commas at all." But I guarantee there are many differences of opinion. This question is based on the premise that all the commas are over the top.

This question is a near-duplicate but specifically about AP style

You could put commas between alternate letters and it would not produce anything ungrammatical. Wrongly punctuated, certainly. // Rules about using commas in such grey areas as this are rarely cut and dried. Different style guides can come up with differing suggestions. The overriding need is for clarity, lack of ambiguity. Commas are servants. I'd certainly retain the comma between the two distinct numerals to avoid misreadings. The one after 2024 is ...

traditionally preferred, but dropping it doesn't hurt, and there is a modern move towards more minimalist punctuation. However, I'd include it because I'd pause after 2024 if reading aloud. // *Perhaps a mod can rule on spuriousness or not of duplicity, Stuart. I'd say the answers there say neither choice is unacceptable.

What seems much more awkward is trying to make the whole multi-word date-phrase act together to modify meeting; wouldn't it be nicer to say "during the meeting on October 29, 2024," with or without the comma?
